# display.remove(obj) doesn't work, why ? (lua)

Tags: lua

In this program when you tap on the object *moon* the function *changeScene()* should change scene from **end.lua** to **start.lua** (in order to restart the game).

But in the **start.lua** the *moon* remains on the display.

Therefore in *changeScene()* I add  `display.remove( moon )` but it does not work.

I tried `moon:removeSelf()` and `sceneGroup:remove(3)` too.

Furthermore I do not know why `moon:removeSelf()` gives this error:

> ```
> ERROR: Runtime error
>                     end.lua:13: attempt to index global 'moon' (a nil value)
>                     stack traceback: 
>                       end.lua:13: in function '?' 
>                       ?: in function <?:190>
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

**end.lua**

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()


-- create()
function scene:create( event )

   local sceneGroup = self.view

   local function changeScene()
       --moon:removeSelf()
       --sceneGroup:remove(3)
       display.remove( moon )
       --moon = nil
       composer.removeScene("end")
       composer.gotoScene( "start", {effect = "slideUp", time = 500} )
   end

   local text = display.newText(correctAnswers .. "/10 correct ", display.contentCenterX, 280 ,native.systemFont, 50)
   text.y = display.contentCenterY-100
   sceneGroup:insert(text)

   local text2 = display.newText("Press the moon to RESTART ", display.contentCenterX, 280 ,native.systemFont, 20)
   text2.x = display.contentCenterX
   text2.y = display.contentCenterY+200
   transition.blink( text2, { time=2500 } )
   sceneGroup:insert(text2)

   local floor = display.newImageRect( "floor.png", 300, 50 )
   floor.x = display.contentCenterX
   floor.y = display.viewableContentHeight+100

   local moon = display.newImageRect( "balloon.png", 112, 112 )
   moon.x = math.random( 40,display.contentWidth-40 )
   moon.y = 50
   moon.alpha = 0.8

   local physics = require( "physics" )
   physics.start()
   physics.addBody( floor, "static" )
   physics.addBody( moon, "dynamic", { radius=50, bounce=0.5 } )

   moon:addEventListener( "tap", changeScene )

end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to use local variables inside of functions. [But variables can only be used when they are in scope](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.5).

Of course, variables that are in the parameter list of a function definition are in scope inside of the function. But variables which are *not* in the parameter list may also be used, provided that they are in scope at the time of function definition. In OP code, the `changeScene` function has no parameters, so any variables used in the function *must* be in scope at the time of function definition. The variable `moon` is a local variable, which is in scope in the block in which it is declared, *after the point of definition*. So, `moon` is *not* in scope when `changeScene` is defined. One way to fix this problem is to move the definition of `moon` to a point *before* the definition of `changeScene`:

```
local moon = display.newImageRect("balloon.png", 112, 112)
moon.x = math.random(40,display.contentWidth - 40)
moon.y = 50
moon.alpha = 0.8

local function changeScene ()
    display.remove(moon)
    composer.removeScene("end")
    composer.gotoScene("start", {effect = "slideUp", time = 500})
end
```

Answer (score -1):

in Lua, when we work with a function, whenever we are going to call a variable inside it, it must be `local`, but when we are inside a function calling a variable outside it, it must be `global`.

Remove the `local` in the `moon` variable declaration and see if that solves the problem

Answer (score -1):

When using functions its fine to use a defined variable inside but you need to make sure 1 its local and 2 if its outside its global

try taking the local out of the defined moon variable and you might be able to fix it
:D

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.